# How to Assert Two doubles in JUnit Using assertEquals with Epsilon?

Tags: java, junit

assertEquals for doubles is deprecated. I found that the form with Epsilon should be used. It is because of impossible 100% strictness of doubles. But anyway I need to compare two doubles (expected and actual result), but I don't know how to do it.

At the moment my test looks like:

```
@Test
public void testCalcPossibleDistancePercentageCount() {
    int percentage = 100;
    assertEquals("Wrong max possible value for %" + percentage, 110.42, processor.calcPossibleValue(percentage));
    percentage = 75;
    /*corresponding assertions*/
}
```

Here are 3 double values I receive and which I want to check with JUnit: 110.42, 2760.5 and 10931.58.
How should JUnit test look like with assertions for them? I receive them as a result of calculation in a method:

```
processor.calcPossibleValue(allowed_percentage){return /*Some weird formulae here*/;}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add a fourth parameter to the `assertEquals` call: the threshold within which two doubles should be considered "equal".  Your call should look like this:

```
assertEquals("Wrong max possible value for %" + percentage, 110.42,
        processor.calcPossibleValue(percentage), 0.01);
```

The above call would indicate that if the value returned by `processor.calcPossibleValue(percentage)` is within ± 0.01 of `110.42`, then the two values are considered equal.  You can change this value to make it as small as is necessary for your application.

See the [JUnit documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is simple and useful.

Answer (score 1):

A Java double uses the [IEEE 754 64-bit format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).  This format has 52 mantissa bits.  When comparing 2 values the epsilon should take into account the magnitude of the expected value.

For example, 0.01 might work okay for 110.42 however it won't work if the expected value is > 2<sup>52</sup>.  The magnitude of 2<sup>52</sup> is so large that 0.01 would be lost due to precision (i.e. only 52-bit mantissa bits).  For example, 2<sup>52</sup> + 0.01 == 2<sup>52</sup>.

With that in mind, epsilon should be scaled to the expected value.  For example, expected value ÷ 2<sup>52 - 3</sup> or 110.42 ÷ 2<sup>52 - 3</sup> = 1.96... x 10<sup>-13</sup>.  I chose 2<sup>52 - 3</sup> since this will give a tolerance in the 3 least significant bits in the mantissa.

One caution is that if the expected value is 0.0 then this formula computes epsilon as 0.0 which may be too strict for a particular case.

Another caution is that NaN and ±∞ are not handled.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.assertTrue("Not equals", expectedDouble -  actualDouble == 0);
```

There is no need to involve epsilon or delta.

Answer (score 1):

**Assert is Deprecated**

```
assertTrue("message like not equal ",expectedresult-actual == 0);
```