# how to return value in a method in Java

Tags: java, class, return

I got a question about how to return values when the method invoked in main method, here is my partial code:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Race {

private ArrayList<Car>cars;


 public Race(){
cars=new ArrayList<Car>();
}

public Car find(double position){
for(Car d:cars){
    if(d.getPosition()==position){
        return d;
    }
}
return null;
}
 .................
```

When I called the find method in main class:

```
     public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Race race=new Race();
    Car mazda=new Car("Mazda",1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0);
    Car honda=new Car("Honda",1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0);
    race.addCars(mazda);
    race.addCars(honda);

     System.out.println(race.find(1.0).getName());
```

The third values are position, which means mazda and honda have the same position and it is supposed to print both, but when I run it, it only prints mazda, I am confused, please advise, cheers!

Comment: On a side note, you should not do `d.getPosition()==position` because floats have limited precision and cannot be compared like that. Either use ints or do something like `Math.abs(d.getPosition()-position) < 0.000001`.

Comment: return a collection or pass it as a parameter to the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here:

1. You can only return one thing from a method.  Your method returns type `Car`, which means you will return literally *one* `Car` object.  If you want to return multiple, you will need to either return an array of cars (`Car[]`) or a collection of cars (e.g. `List<Car>`, `Set<Car>`, etc.).
2. Using doubles with exact equality is a bad idea.  Because of rounding and stuff that's potentially out of the scope of this question, `double` values may not always be exactly what you'd expect (e.g. `1.0` might not always mean `1.0`, it could be `0.999999...`, etc).  Either use integers, or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11808862/722760) (or similar) on how to compare `double` values in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can only return one value from a method. But you can return a `List`:

```
public List<Car> find(double position) {
    List<Car> ret = new ArrayList<Car>();
    for (Car c : cars) 
        if (c.getPosition() == position)
            ret.add(c);
    return ret;
}
```

If this is all you do, you will get this output:

```
[mazda, toyota]
```

If you want each one on a separate line, you will need to iterate through the list in `main` and print each one:

```
for (Car c : race.find(1.0)) 
    System.out.println(c.getName());
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution, but how should I wrtie System.out.println in the main() method, my old way is not working with your solution, the getName() method is not working

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: 1, you can only return one `Object` from a method, and 2, your method returns immediately when it finds a `Car` in the requested position.  You need to take a look at your return type and make some adjustments if you want to be able to print more than one car.

Instead, do something like this:

```
public List<Car> find(double position){
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
for(Car d:cars){
    if(d.getPosition()==position){
        cars.add(d);
    }
}
return cars;
}
```

You would then need to do some iterating back in your `main()` method to print out each returned car, like so:

```
for(Car car : race.find(1.0))
{
    System.out.println(car.getName());
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution, but how should I wrtie System.out.println in the main() method, my old way is not working with your solution, the getName() method is not working

Comment: As I said, You would then need to do some iterating back in your `main()` method to print out each returned car.

Comment: @peiwang there I even gave you an example how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your return type from `Car` to `Set<Car>`. The reason is that when you find the first car (in this case the mazda) you execute the line `return d;`. That means its the end of your function. What you need to do is declare a `Set<Car>` locally in the function, and intead of writing `return d` you write `Set.add(d);`

Comment: Personally would argue that a List would be a better choice than a Set in this case